# OPC UA Robotics - Schema

Tags: robotics, opc-ua

The OPC UA Companion Spec for Robotics defines `new Enumeration DataTypes`

- AxisMotionProfileEnumeration (used under AxisType)
- ExecutionModeEnumeration (used under TaskControlType)
- MotionDeviceCategoryEnumeration (used under MotionDeviceType)
- OperationalModeEnumeration (used under SafetyStateType)

However, `no official bsd file` was released as part of the OPC UA Robotics Schema. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the [answer](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/issues/75#issuecomment-719587316) of OPC Foundation, also here:

> The BSD is embedded in the NodeSet as Base64 data.
> It can be extracted with a copy and paste.
> We have requested that all specification writers provide the BSD when their spec is
> released.
> It will take a bit of time for current specifications to catch up.